# Determine the value of the sum to infinity of $(u_{r+1} + \frac{1}{2^r})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Determine the value of $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\Bigl(u_{r+1} + \frac{1}{2^r}\Bigr)$$.

In earlier parts of the question, it is given $\displaystyle u_r= \frac{2}{(r+1)(r+3)}$, which when expressed in partial fractions is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{r+1}-\frac{1}{r+3}$.

Also previously, the question asks to show that $$\sum_{r=1}^n u_r = \frac{5}{6}-\frac {1}{n+2} -\frac{1}{n+3}$$ which I managed to.

I have also determined the values of $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty u_r$$ which is $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty u_r= \frac{5}{6}$$

But I don’t know how to solve for

> $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\Bigl(u_{r+1} + \frac{1}{2^r}\Bigr)$$

My attempts so far:

$\displaystyle u_{r+1} =\frac{2}{(r+1+1)(r+1+3)}$

$=\displaystyle\frac{2}{(r+2)(r+4)}$

Let $\displaystyle \frac{2}{(r+2)(r+4)}\equiv \frac{A}{(r+2)(r+4)}$

$2\equiv A(r+4)+B(r+2)$

Let r $=-4,B=-1$

Let $r=-2,A=1$

So, is $\displaystyle u_{r+1} \equiv \frac {1}{r+2}- \frac{1}{r+4}$?

Assuming that it is,$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\Bigl(u_{r+1} + \frac{1}{2^r}\Bigr)$$

= $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\Bigl(\frac{1}{r+2}+\frac{1}{r+4} + \frac{1}{2^r}\Bigr)$$

$=\frac{1}{3}-\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{5}}+\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{4}-\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{6}}+\frac{1}{4}$

$\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{5}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{7}}+\frac{1}{8}$

$\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac{1}{6}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{8}}+\frac{1}{16}$

.....

I don't know how to cancel the middle terms, how should this question be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{r=1}^\infty\Bigl(u_{r+1} + \frac{1}{2^r}\Bigr) & = \sum_{r=1}^\infty u_{r+1} + \sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^r} \\
& = (\sum_{r=1}^\infty u_{r} - u_1) + 1 \\
& = \frac{5}{6} -\frac{1}{4} + 1 \\
& = \frac{10}{12} - \frac{3}{12} + \frac{12}{12} \\
& = \frac{19}{12}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note I used $\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^r}$ is the sum of an infinite [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), with $a = \frac{1}{2}$ being the first term and $r = \frac{1}{2}$ being the common ratio, so the sum is $\frac{a}{1-r} = 1$.

Comment: May I ask why $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty u_r+1 = -u_1$$ ?

Comment: @gc3941d I've adjusted my answer to try to make what I was doing more clear. Note the $+ 1$ part comes from the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^r}$. Instead, what I used is that $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}u_{r+1} = u_2 + u_3 + \ldots = (u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + \ldots) - u_1 = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}u_{r} - u_1$. In particular, I added $u_1$ to the infinite sum, so I had to then subtract it to not change its value. I hope it's more clear to you now.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$U_{r+1}=\frac{2}{(r+2)(r+4)}= 2 \left[\left(\frac{1}{r+2}-\frac{1}{r+3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{r+3}-\frac{1}{r+4}\right) \right]= [(F_r-F_{r+1})+(F_{r+1}-F_{r+2})], F_r=\frac{1}{r+2}.$$

Now telescoping summation can be done easily.